# Implementing getchar in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement `gecthar`, using `read`, the problem is when I use `my_getchar()` with `printf` my function executes before `printf`.

```
#ifndef BUFF_SIZE
#define BUFF_SIZE 1023
#endif

int my_getchar(void)
{
    static char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    static char *chr;
    int         ret;

    if ((ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
         chr = buff;
        return (*chr);
    }
    return (EOF);
}
```

in my `main()`

```
char c;

printf("Enter character: "); // if I put '\n' line here, it works fine
c = my_getchar();

printf("Character entered: ");
putchar(c);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to flush the output to stdout:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/629409-fflush-stdout is a similar question

`printf` will typically do this for you if you have a newline (as you've found) but not if you don't.